# Why is tuple_size a trait and not a member

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, traits, one-definition-rule

Why is `tuple_size` a free trait and not a member variables/typedefs within the class?  The latter has a much smaller risk of causing ODR violations.

Is there a concrete use case where having a trait `tuple_size` is better than defining this inline within the class?  Is there a motivating case similar to that of `iterator_traits` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742025/5501675) The only one I see is the benefit it brings with incomplete types.  Though not entirely sure what a use case for that is

`tuple_size` could easily be made a member something like this

```
class Something {
public:
    static constexpr auto tuple_size = 3;
};
```

And then the free implementation of the `tuple_size` trait can be

```
template <typename T, EnableIfHasTupleSize<std::decay_t<T>>* = nullptr>
struct tuple_size 
    : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
                                    std::decay_t<T>::tuple_size> 
{};
```

Such an implementation would bring both the benefits of having a `tuple_size` that can work with incomplete types if specialized as well as offering the security of the member constant where needed.  Similar to `iterator_traits`

---

This example was given to me by [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) recently of how tuple_size can easily cause ODR violations.

```
struct X { int a; };

template<> struct std::tuple_size<X>;
template<size_t I> struct std::tuple_element<I, X> { using type = int; };
template<size_t I> int get(X) { return 1; }


call_func_that_checks_value_of_tuple_size(X{});

template<> struct std::tuple_size<X> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 3> {};

call_func_that_checks_value_of_tuple_size(X{});
```

Compilers are able to pick up on this, however if this is split between translation units, its very hard for a compiler to catch this.

Answer (score 4):

In C++17 structured bindings require that a type support `std::tuple_size<T>`, ADL-enabled `get<std::size_t>`, and `std::tuple_element<std::size_t, T>`.

If a type supports all 3, structured binding works.

This permits you to take a type provided by a 3rd party, like [QPair](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpair.html), and without modifying their source code or requiring them to update, use it in a structured binding way in your code.

If `tuple_size` was a member of `tuple` (and `array` and `pair`), then we would have had to add a `tuple_size` trait in C++17 to have this capability anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

`std::tuple` was implemented in the technical report 1 before entering the standard.

This was before C++11 existed, hence, no constexpr functions. Since `std::tuple_size` is a constant value, it made sense to make it a template at the time to make it a constant expression (it could perfectly be a `.size()` constexpr member AFAIK with no problem).

As for the non-member, `std::array` also supports `std::tuple_size` and any struct could support it in theory.

So I think these are the potential reasons for the decision but I do not know the real decisions behind it, I just reasoned it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is symmetry with std::get (that can not easily be member because [glorious C++ grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313638/700825)).