# Compile errors for simple CRTP case with dependent types

Tags: c++, crtp

I'm trying to use a simple form of CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) as I've got several classes, each with several related classes, and I want a means of binding them together (eg I've got classes like Widget, Doobry and Whatsit, with related classes WidgetHandle, DoobryHandle and WhatsitHandle).

Each class that I'm using to inherit from `Base` adds a `value_type` typedef so that the base class can refer to it as `typename TWrapper::value_type`.

```
struct WidgetHandle {};

template <typename TWrapper>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(typename TWrapper::value_type value_) 
        : value(value_) {}

    typename TWrapper::value_type   value;
};

class Widget : public Base<Widget>
{
public:
    typedef WidgetHandle value_type;

    Widget(WidgetHandle value_) : Base<Widget>(value_) {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Widget i(WidgetHandle());
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm getting compilation errors:

```
scratch1.cpp(10): error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of 'Widget'
scratch1.cpp(16) : see declaration of 'Widget'
scratch1.cpp : see reference to class template instantiation 'Base<TWrapper>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TWrapper=Widget
1>          ]
scratch1.cpp(10): error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of 'Widget'
```

This is with VS2010, though I'm getting similar errors with clang.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `Widget` is incomplete type when you pass it as a parameter to `Base`.

Comment: I don't see `value_type` defined anywhere, in fact.

Comment: @PetrBudnik It is, at the start of `Widget` body.

Comment: @jrok I stand corrected.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652155/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type) is one more possible workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of Base to take the handle type as a second parameter to avoid the circular dependency.

```
struct WidgetHandle {};

template <typename TWrapper, typename HandleType>
class Base
{
public:
    typedef HandleType value_type;

    Base(HandleType value_) 
        : value(value_) {}

    HandleType value;
};

class Widget : public Base<Widget, WidgetHandle>
{
public:
    Widget(WidgetHandle value_) : Base(value_) {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Widget i(WidgetHandle());
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use a traits class to get the WidgeHandle type for Widget.

```
struct WidgetHandle {};
class Widget;

template<class T>
struct Handle
{
};

template<>
struct Handle<Widget>
{
  typedef WidgetHandle type;  
};

template <typename TWrapper, typename HandleType = Handle<TWrapper>::type>
class Base
{
public:
    typedef HandleType value_type;

    Base(HandleType value_) 
        : value(value_) {}

    HandleType value;
};

class Widget : public Base<Widget>
{
public:
    Widget(WidgetHandle value_) : Base(value_) {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Widget i(WidgetHandle());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know I can add extra types to the template definition, but it's unfortunate to require this if TWrapper has a means of specifying the type that it's bound to

Comment: Use default template parameter to get the handle type from the traits class - then at least the client code will look the same.

Comment: That does the trick. In my case I have several related types per class, so tying them together with the Handle traits class means that they can be all declared in one.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have circular dependencies: Base needs the Widget value_type which is unknown at Base instantiation.

Possible Solution would be: Pass the value_type as a Base template parameter, use an extra Traits template, ...

**Example**:

```
template <typename W> 
struct WidgetTraits {};

template <typename W>
class Base
{
    public:
    typedef typename WidgetTraits<W>::value_type value_type;
};

class Widget;

template<>
struct WidgetTraits<Widget>
{
    typedef WidgetHandle value_type;
};

class Widget : public Base<Widget>
{
};
```

**Another (slightly different) Example**:

```
template <typename C, typename A>
class B : public A
{
    public:
    typedef typename A::value_type value_type;
};


class A
{
    public:
    typedef WidgetHandle value_type;
};


class C : public B<C, A>
{
};
```

Comment: That's true in general, but CRTP uses this technique extensively does it not? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: ok, the traits template sounds like it may be better - what would that look like?

Comment: The traits solution is more complicated ... I'd go for the additional template parameter.